# POS tagging using nltk takes time

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am trying to get POS tags using nltk, i think it should take less then or around 1 sencond for processing small text. But 2-3 sentence it takes 20-25 second.

```
import nltk,re, time
def findPos( text):
    start_time = time.time()
    try:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        print [ x[0] for x in pos_tags if x[1] == "NN" or "NNP"]
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.format_exc()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

findPos(raw_input())
```

Any suggestion how to reduce time ere?

Comment: for me this take less than a second.
    `nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize("And now for something completely different"))` (even if I multiply the tokenize result by 10)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, we can help you better if you provide these information. Can you post the text that you have input? What is your machine's specification (CPU speed and RAM)? Are you connecting to a cloud and how are you timing the function?

Comment: @alvas: yes, it is on amazon t2 micro instance. And input is 5-10 sentence long

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is pos\_tag() so painfully slow and can this be avoided?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829160/why-is-pos-tag-so-painfully-slow-and-can-this-be-avoided)