# POS-Tagger is incredibly slow

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I am using `nltk` to generate n-grams from sentences by first removing given stop words. However, `nltk.pos_tag()` is extremely slow taking up to 0.6 sec on my CPU (Intel i7).

The output:

```
['The first time I went, and was completely taken by the live jazz band and atmosphere, I ordered the Lobster Cobb Salad.']
0.620481014252
["It's simply the best meal in NYC."]
0.640982151031
['You cannot go wrong at the Red Eye Grill.']
0.644664049149
```

The code:

```
for sentence in source:

    nltk_ngrams = None

    if stop_words is not None:   
        start = time.time()
        sentence_pos = nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
        print time.time() - start

        filtered_words = [word for (word, pos) in sentence_pos if pos not in stop_words]
    else:
        filtered_words = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)
```

Is this really that slow or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the text that you have input? What is your machine's specification (CPU speed and RAM)? Are you connecting to a cloud and how are you timing the function? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558836/pos-tagging-using-nltk-takes-time

Comment: @alvas It's an Intel i7 (stated in the question). 16GB RAM. No, it's not in the cloud it's local. You can see in my code example how I time it.

Comment: You need to parallelize your solution if you have a huge dataset. Otherwise (if you can hold the tagged sentences in RAM), simply collect all the tagged sentence then do the filter afterwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pos_tag_sents` for tagging multiple sentences:

```
>>> import time
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> from nltk import pos_tag_sents
>>> sents = brown.sents()[:10]
>>> start = time.time(); pos_tag(sents[0]); print time.time() - start
0.934092998505
>>> start = time.time(); [pos_tag(s) for s in sents]; print time.time() - start
9.5061340332
>>> start = time.time(); pos_tag_sents(sents); print time.time() - start 
0.939551115036
```

Comment: Very nice! Using `pos_tag_sents()` improves the performance a lot. It's strange why this is the case. It seems `pos_tag()` repeats some initialization or something like that.

Comment: It's a question with a pretty long answer but if you ask a separate question on how and why it's faster, someone might answer. if no one answers, i'll answer when I'm free-er tomorrow evening =)

Comment: [There you go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829160/why-is-pos-tag-so-painfully-slow-and-can-this-be-avoided) ;)

Comment: Voila, someone else answered it =)

Answer (score 8):

```
nltk pos_tag is defined as:
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
def pos_tag(tokens, tagset=None):
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
    return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
```

so each call to pos_tag instantiates the perceptrontagger module which takes much of the computation time.You can save this time by directly calling tagger.tag yourself as:

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
tagger=PerceptronTagger()
sentence_pos = tagger.tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

Comment: Is there any way to decrease time for ner using nltk

Comment: Its also worth noting that using the tagger directly instead of pos_tag allows you to afterwards map the tags into annother tagset, without having to re-compute them by using nltk.tag.mapping map_tag as done in https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L134C22-L134C22

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for another POS tagger with fast performances in Python, you might want to try [RDRPOSTagger](http://rdrpostagger.sourceforge.net/). For example, on English POS tagging, the tagging speed is 8K words/second for a single threaded implementation in Python, using a computer of Core 2Duo 2.4GHz. You can  get faster tagging speed by simply using the multi-threaded mode. RDRPOSTagger obtains very competitive accuracies in comparison to state-of-the-art taggers and now supports pre-trained models for 40 languages. See experimental results in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.4021).

Answer (score 0):

if you use nested list you should flatten and use single list
this will hep you in incresing the speed of StanfordPOSTagger

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).