# Stanford NER with python NLTK fails with strings containing multiple "!!"s?

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Suppose this is my `filecontent`:

> When they are over 45 years old!! It would definitely help Michael Jordan.

Below is my code for tagging setences.

```
st = NERTagger('stanford-ner/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz', 'stanford-ner/stanford-ner.jar')
tokenized_sents = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(filecontent)]  
taggedsents = st.tag_sents(tokenized_sents)
```

I would expect both `tokenized_sents` and `taggedsents` contain the same number of sentences.

But here is what they contain:

```
for ts in tokenized_sents:
    print "tok   ", ts

for ts in taggedsents:
    print "tagged    ",ts

>> tok    ['When', 'they', 'are', 'over', '45', 'years', 'old', '!', '!']
>> tok    ['It', 'would', 'definitely', 'help', '.']
>> tagged     [(u'When', u'O'), (u'they', u'O'), (u'are', u'O'), (u'over', u'O'), (u'45', u'O'), (u'years', u'O'), (u'old', u'O'), (u'!', u'O')]
>> tagged     [(u'!', u'O')]
>> tagged     [(u'It', u'O'), (u'would', u'O'), (u'definitely', u'O'), (u'help', u'O'), (u'Michael', u'PERSON'), (u'Jordan', u'PERSON'), (u'.', u'O')]
```

This is due to having doulbe "!" at the end of the supposed first sentence. Do I have to remove double "!"s before using `st.tag_sents()`

How should I resolve this?

Comment: There are no `named entities` in your data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition . Try a sentence like 'Michael Jordan went to Apple Inc. to buy and iPad Air for his daugther Layla Jordan'

Comment: The sentence tokenization is a weird thing so if you change `['!', '!']` to `['!!']`, it should work. You're working with noisy data. Stanford tools are built on clean data, so it might not scale to any domain / genre

Comment: it's not a prob with having no NEs (have added a ne to the string but still the same).

Comment: Yeah so its a weired problem with tokenization.

Comment: no idea why it can't just use the sentences I passed to 'tag_sents()' without further tokenizing!

Comment: follow StanfordNLPHelp instructions if you're not bent on at must to use NLTK, otherwise, it will take some time for an answer as to why the NLTK API don't work as you expect. And yet some more time for NLTK to improve the API such that it keeps the tokenization provided by the user.

Comment: You could replace the `!` with a null character so that it does not fail.

Comment: @RohanAmrute yes but then there could be other characters that fails as well

Comment: I think there is no fool-proof way of of doing this. Have to test it by trial and error technique

Answer (score 1):

If you follow my solution from the other question instead of using nltk you will get JSON that properly splits this text into two sentences.

Link to previous question: [how to speed up NE recognition with stanford NER with python nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748554/how-to-speed-up-ne-recognition-with-stanford-ner-with-python-nltk)