# Why is pos_tag() so painfully slow and can this be avoided?

Tags: python, nltk

I want to be able to get POS-Tags of sentences one by one like in this manner:

```
def __remove_stop_words(self, tokenized_text, stop_words):

    sentences_pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized_text)  
    filtered_words = [word for (word, pos) in sentences_pos 
                      if pos not in stop_words and word not in stop_words]

    return filtered_words
```

But the problem is that `pos_tag()` takes about a second for each sentence. There is another option to use `pos_tag_sents()` to do this batch-wise and speed things up. But my life would be easier if I could do this sentence by sentence.

Is there a way to do this faster?

Comment: What version of nltk are you using? (i.e. `nltk.__version__`)

Comment: Background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676526/pos-tagger-is-incredibly-slow#comment55128218_33677051

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For nltk version 3.1, inside [`nltk/tag/__init__.py`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L110), `pos_tag` is defined like this:

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
def pos_tag(tokens, tagset=None):
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
    return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
```

So each call to `pos_tag` first instantiates `PerceptronTagger` which takes some time because it involves [loading a pickle file](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/perceptron.py#L141). `_pos_tag` [simply calls `tagger.tag`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L82) when `tagset` is `None`.
So you can save some time by loading the file *once*, and calling `tagger.tag` yourself instead of calling `pos_tag`:

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
tagger = PerceptronTagger() 
def __remove_stop_words(self, tokenized_text, stop_words, tagger=tagger):
    sentences_pos = tagger.tag(tokenized_text)  
    filtered_words = [word for (word, pos) in sentences_pos 
                      if pos not in stop_words and word not in stop_words]

    return filtered_words
```

---

`pos_tag_sents` uses the same trick as above -- [it instantiates `PerceptronTagger` once](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tag/__init__.py#L127) before calling `_pos_tag` many times. So you'll get a comparable gain in performance using the above code as you would by refactoring and calling `pos_tag_sents`.

---

Also, if `stop_words` is a long list, you may save a bit of time by making `stop_words` a set:

```
stop_words = set(stop_words)
```

since checking membership in a set (e.g. `pos not in stop_words`) is a `O(1)` (constant time) operation while checking membership in a list is a `O(n)` operation (i.e. it requires time which grows proportionally to the length of the list.)

Comment: Now THAT is what I am talking about! It is strange thought that I have to do it like this. I mean, how often does it happen that somebody wants just to tag *one* single sentence? Would be interesting to know why the developers decided that this is a good idea but I am happy to have a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: Well, `pos_tag()` is a function. If you call a function you are expecting that after the function is executed you get a result and nothing lingers around in memory.

Comment: @StefanFalk, `pos_tag` is meant to be a duck type. And part of the reason to keep it is for back-compatibility with NLTK < 3.1. Always use the specific tagger when possible. =)

Comment: @unutbu nice answer! One thing to note if order of words for the `filtered_words` is not an issue it might be faster to do this `set(zip(*tagger.tag(tokenized_text))[0]).difference(stop_words)` =)

Comment: is this still the case? bizarrely, implementing it this way takes more time for me